# Swift5 Can't record audio on mac os using AVAudioRecorder ( Error : [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID )

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Making audio recorder application for Mac OS.
Have one trouble when I using AVAudioRecorder.
Don't crash but always shows this error.

Error : [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID
...

Error : HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine

** This is my code

```
var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!

let filepath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")

let settings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
]



do {
    audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: filepath, settings: settings)
    audioRecorder.record()

    sleep(10)

    audioRecorder.stop()

} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Check Capabilities and info.plist.

Comment: I didn't set sandbox. And this is command line app.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem.

The original CLT project doesn't contain Info.plist file.
You have to set Info.plist and allow "Audio Input" of "Resource Access".

Solution

1. I have made Info.plist file myself and set "Microphone Usage Description" on it.
2. The main is to add Info.plist and set Info.plist to project setting.
   ( ** Build Setting / Packaging / Info.plist File : Info.plist )
3. Add Hardened Runtime on Project
   ( ** goto Signing & Capabilities and Add "Hardened Runtime" by click "+Capabilty" )
4. Allow "Audio Input"
   ( ** Signing & Capabilities / Hardened Runtime / Resource Access / Audio Input )
5. After setting above, built project.

Can't run directly on Xcode.
When you run on Xcode, app would be crashed.
Must run app on Terminal.

Comment: Thanks! My issue was specifically adding the "Microphone Usage Description" to the Info.plist. Without it, the app would silently fail and the recorded audio file would be silent. Once I added the Microphone Usage Description, macOS prompted for access to the microphone and the audio would then be recorded properly.