# AVAudioSession Error with Shared Instance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio, avaudiosession

I am having some trouble working with the AVAudioEngine and Apple's dictation to record and process external microphone inputs. My code is as follows:

```
func recognizeAudioStream() {
        let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()

        //performs speech recognition on live audio; as audio is captured, call append
        //to request object, call endAudio() to end speech recognition
        var recognitionRequest: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?

        //determines & edits state of speech recognition task (end, start, cancel, etc)
        var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?

        let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()


        func startRecording() throws{

            //cancel previous audio task
            recognitionTask?.cancel()
            recognitionTask = nil

            print("here2")
            //get info from microphone
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            print("here2-")
            try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .measurement, options: .duckOthers)
            print("here2--")
            try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            print("here2----")

            print("here2")
            let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
            print("here3")

            //audio buffer; takes a continuous input of audio and recognizes speech
            recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
            print("here4")
            //allows device to print results of your speech before you're done talking
            recognitionRequest?.shouldReportPartialResults = true
            print("here5")


            recognitionTask = speechRecognizer!.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest!) {result, error in

                var isFinal = false
                
                print("here")
                
                if let result = result{ //if we can let result be the nonoptional version of result, then
                    isFinal = result.isFinal
                    print("Text: \(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)")
                    
                }
                
                if error != nil || result!.isFinal{ //if an error occurs or we're done speaking
                    
                    audioEngine.stop()
                    inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
                    
                    recognitionTask = nil
                    recognitionRequest = nil

                    let bufferText = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString.components(separatedBy: (" "))
                    print("completed buffer")
                    
                    self.addToDictionary(wordNames: bufferText)
                    self.populateTempWords()
                    
                    wordsColl.reloadData()
//
                    do{
                        try startRecording()
                    }
                    catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
                }
            
            }
            
            //configure microphone; let the recording format match with that of the bus we are using
            let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
            
            //contents of buffer will be dumped into recognitionRequest and into result, where
            //it will then be transcribed and printed out
            //1024 bytes = dumping "limit": once buffer fills to 1024 bytes, it is appended to recognitionRequest
            inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
                recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
            }
            
            audioEngine.prepare()
            try audioEngine.start()
        }
        
        do{
            try startRecording()
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
        
        
    }
```

From an entirely inefficient debugging session, I was able to determine that the line `let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()` produces the first error in the log, while I'm certain the `recognitionTask` closure produces the second error message:

```
here2
2021-06-23 22:45:22.707332-0500 DictoCounter[38814:6314709] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 
here2-
here2--
here2----
here2
here3
here4
here5
2021-06-23 22:45:22.953963-0500 DictoCounter[38814:6314846] [aurioc] 323: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2
reg
```

I should also note that I was able to detect and process audio without errors just a few months ago with this same code, on the same Macbook (and same xcworkspace project). This leads me to believe that it is probably not a code issue, but more of a settings issue.

I did a search prior to posting this question:
[Swift5 Can't record audio on mac os using AVAudioRecorder ( Error : [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247492/swift5-cant-record-audio-on-mac-os-using-avaudiorecorder-error-plugin-add) seems to indicate the problem is with the info.plist file. However, I've updated it to allow both speech recognition and microphone detection.

[image]

Please let me know if you need any more information. Looking forward to solving this problem!

Comment: This is still happening to me, today, on the latest versions of everything. Sigh.